# Running a Java project remotely

Tags: java, eclipse, build-automation

I've got this new project at work. We are using Eclipse for the project. There are two run configurations, server and client. I have to launch the server and the client independently, and connect to the server using the client. Now, it so happens that this has to be done on both Windows and Linux. (four possible combinations: WS-LC, WC-LS, WS-WC, LS-LC, where W-windows, L-linux, C-client and S-server)

I have Linux on my machine (in which Eclipse is running) and run Windows on a VM. Is there a way I can make Eclipse launch the application in the VM?

I understand I have to build the application locally to a shared folder and send a launch command to windows (using openssh?, not sure). What are the best practices used in this scenario.

**EDIT:** I need to use this during development, to test my changes to the code. The same application provides both client & server. (yes, horrible, i know :X )

Comment: 1) Why do you need Eclipse to launch the application? do you need to compile it first before launching?

2) Do you have one application supplying both client and server functions?

Comment: 1) Yes, when I change the code base I need to recompile the application. 2) Yes, the same application supplies both client and server.

Comment: Why not make a bat/sh script that compiles the source code (ant, maven) and then simply launches the entry point class? why do you need Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

You can publish the server functions as JMX Beans using the MBean interface standard. Then use JMX Console to remotely connect to the server JVM and launch the application.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has integration points for remote servers, look to "tomcat configuration" for an example of how it integrates with one remote server.

Whether your application can use an existing server integration solution or not depends heavily on details which aren't present.  If you want to actually launch a stand-alone Java process from your remote machine, you generally need a program to capture the request and launch the process.